# MVC4 partial view jquery navigator.userAgent issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

having an issue where the javascript renders and runs corretly for the first page using a layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1, IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/less")        
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="skin-wrap">
        <header>
            @Html.Partial("_Header")
        </header>
        <section class="detail">
            <section class="menu-col">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Menu"); }
            </section>
            <section class="detail-col">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 </body>
</html>
```

but after a menu item is loaded and a different view that uses the same layout renders there are several permission denied errors whenever jqueryui (version 1.10.xx) or site.js calls

```
 navigator.userAgent
```

I've seen all the answers referencing registry settings for Internet Explorer but the settings are all set to what was suggested and is not really a viable solution for users to have to change.

I assume we are just rendering scripts incorrectly.

errors in ie

```
SCRIPT70: Permission denied 
site.js, line 3 character 1234
```

this js throws the error as well

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
     alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
});
```

first time the view loads it works fine, second time it throws the permission denied error.

Comment: Add the errors please. Code seems right. If the problem is with site.js try taking out the ~ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")
```

to be sure it render correctly ...

Comment: $(document).on('ready', function () {
    alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
});

Answer (score 0):

for a bundle you need to use scripts.render for a single file you need a script tag.  try changing the site.js reference to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content( "~/Scripts/site.js" )"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> after a menu item is loaded and a different view that uses the same layout renders there are several permission denied errors whenever jqueryui (version 1.10.xx) or site.js calls

It is only a speculation but have you thoroughly checked the View that causes this script to fail.. Perhaps a closer look might reveal why this is happening. Maybe you are using some other scripts in that view which may make this script to cause such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think alert gets blocked. Try this.

```
$(document).on('ready', function () { console.log(window.navigator.userAgent); });
```